# How can i recreate a python if statement to have the property of 'LIKE' in SQL?

Tags: python, arcgis

I have a python if statement

```
def FindLabel ( [Area_wl], [OWNER], [APN] ):
    if [OWNER] == 'PELT KENNETH D':
        return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '7'>" + [OWNER] + "\n" + [APN] + "</FNT></CLR>"
    elif [OWNER] == 'PELT PAMELA KAY':
        return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '7'>" + [OWNER] + "\n" + [APN] + "</FNT></CLR>"
    elif [OWNER] == 'PELT JONATHAN VAN':
        return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '7'>" + [OWNER] + "\n" + [APN] + "</FNT></CLR>"
    elif [OWNER] == 'ROBERTS RICHARD F':
        return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '7'>" + [OWNER] + "\n" + [APN] + "</FNT></CLR>"      
    else:
        return [OWNER] + "\n" + [APN]
```

I want to make this statement more efficient, kind of similar to an SQL query of `if [owner] like %Pelt%` or `if [owner] like %Robert%`.

Right now the python code is too tedious and long.
This is a labeling code for ArcPro, GIS software.

Comment: What are those square brackets doing? You can't use square brackets in the parameter list of a function definition.

Comment: You can just say `if "Pelt" in owner:`

Comment: @Barmar If you really want it to be more SQL like, it would be case insensitive. `if "pelt" in owner.lower()`

Comment: @mypetlion That depends on the collation of the column, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The Python equivalent of

```
owner LIKE '%Pelt%'
```

is:

```
'Pelt' in owner
```

`str1 in str2` is `True` when `str1` is a substring of `str2`.

If you want this to be case-insensitive, use:

```
'pelt' in owner.lower()
```

If you're going to search for multiple strings, you should probably set another variable:

```
owner_low = owner.lower()
```

and then test that, rather than repeatedly calling `lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
OWNERS_LIST = ['PELT KENNETH D', 'PELT PAMELA KAY', 'PELT JONATHAN VAN', 'ROBERTS RICHARD F']

def FindLabel(Area_wl, OWNER, APN):
    if OWNER in OWNERS_LIST:
        return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '7'>{}\n{}</FNT></CLR>".format(OWNER, APN)      
    else:
        return "{}\n{}".format(OWNER, APN)
```